# Defining inheritance in prototype of object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm implementing functions in javascript that inherit from a parent class. It works perfectly with this style of code.

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype = {
    constructor: Foo,
    name: 'foo',
    tostring: function()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
};

function Bar(){}

Bar.prototype = new Foo();
Bar.prototype.name = 'bar';

var b = new Bar();
console.log(b.tostring());    // says 'bar'
```

This is okay. But I have a lot of properties in Bar and I don't want to repeat Bar.prototype.someProp every time so I used the shorthand version and it isn't inheriting.

```
function Bar(){}
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
Bar.prototype = {
    constructor: Bar,
    name: 'bar'
};

console.log(b.tostring());   // doesn't work since the method doesn't exist
```

I'm assuming Bar.prototype is being overwritten by the native Object of Javascript. How can I inherit using the shorthand `Bar.prototype = {}` and avoid repetition?

Comment: Why are you modifying the prototype instead of just defining functions on the object?

Comment: Kindly elaborate, @David

Comment: See here: http://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Method_and_property_definitions#Method_and_property_definitions

For debugging purposes, and the safety of the language, it is best to not touch the prototype of an object usually.

Comment: @david: that doesn't make sense for custom "classes".

Comment: @David "The safety of the language" is FUD. Why not use language features if they are there? Just don't change `Object.prototype` itself (the Object class, not individual objects), because it can break wrongly programmed for/in loops. Changing prototypes itself is fine.

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help. People already pointed out you re assign prototype after you inherit, you should mutate it instead. And it's best not to create an instance of parent to use as prototype of child, use Object.create instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use…

```
Bar.prototype = {
  constructor: Bar,
  name: 'bar'
};
```

…you're overwriting everything in the `Bar` prototype, replacing it with a new object. Try setting `Bar.prototype.constructor = xxx` and `Bar.prototype.name = 'bar'` individually.

You could define a helper function to reduce repetition but it's probably not worth it if you only need it once:

```
function extend_with(obj, kv) {
    for (var k in kv) {
        obj[k] = kv[k];
    }
}

extend_with(Bar.prototype, {
    constructor: Bar,
    name: 'bar'
});
```

Comment: If i use it individually, there will be too much repetition which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: It doesn't matter—you can't just set the prototype directly with an object, it will overwrite everything that's already in the prototype. There's helper functions in some JavaScript libraries that individually copy properties (e.g. Object.extend in Prototype.js). ECMAScript 6 will have `Object.assign` for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @thomasfuchs Sorry, I just added another variant to your answer. Does it look reasonable to you?

Comment: @melpomene: yeah, that's basically what `Object.assign` does (in a simplified way) :)

Comment: @thomasfuchs: in es6 one would use `class` I think :)

Comment: @FelixKling Fwiw, if you write code that is backwards-compatible, you can (somewhat) easily polyfill `Object.assign`, whereas you won't be able to emulate ES6 classes.

Comment: That's true, I didn't think if that. I'm using transpilers in most of my projects that I don't even think about backwards compatibility.